# AVX load instruction with increment

Tags: x86, vectorization, simd, avx

Is there an AVX instruction that is able to load four double values from a regular, aligned vector with increments? So if I want a call like `_mm256_load_pd(a)` only with an increment of 4, so that not the values `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]` and `a[3]` are loaded, but `a[0]`, `a[4]`, `a[8]` and `a[12]`?

Comment: You're looking for a gather-load. They exist in Haswell, but they're so slow that it's much faster to use scalar loads + shuffles.

Comment: Can you please give me the intrinsics for this type of load? I don't have Haswell, its IvyBrdige (is gather not AVX2?).

Comment: See Paul's answer. Ivy Bridge only has AVX. It has no gather instructions. But let me reiterate that you really *do not* want to use them. At least not for the current generation of processors.

Comment: Yes, I understood this. I meant for a scalar load. Because I only find loads that read 4 values, like load_pd and in loads for scalars it is stored in all four registers at the same time, not only in the first.

Comment: Could you describe more of what you are trying to do? I mean if for example you read 0,4,8, 12 and then 1,5,9,13, ...you could do e.g. a transpose.

Comment: Sorry for not responding. I was away. I do a solving of a triangular system. Most of the input data is stored in such a way that it can be read directly, but the input/output vector with 3 entries needs to be stored in the form x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ... for the other algorithms in the Code. And here I need for the operations x1. x2. x3. x4 and y1, y2, y3, y4 that are no direct neighbors in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have AVX2 (Haswell and later) then you can use *gathered loads*, e.g. `_mm256_i32gather_pd`. From the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html):

> Synopsis
>
> `__m256d _mm256_i32gather_pd (double const* base_addr, __m128i vindex, const int scale)`
>
> `#include "immintrin.h"`
>
> Instruction: `vgatherdpd ymm, vm64x, ymm`
>
> CPUID Flags: `AVX2`
>
> Description
>
> Gather double-precision (64-bit) floating-point elements from memory using 32-bit indices. 64-bit elements are loaded from addresses starting at base_addr and offset by each 32-bit element in vindex (each index is scaled by the factor in scale). Gathered elements are merged into dst. scale should be 1, 2, 4 or 8.

As noted in the comments already, gathered loads are slow on Haswell, but they may still be worthwhile if you need this access pattern for subsequent 256 bit SIMD operations. Since you're using `double`s though, any benefit may be small, so you might also want to benchmark against a conventional scalar implementation.

Comment: I need the pattern for load and store. For the calculation I can do plain arithmetics without shuffels and masks.